# Regular expression in java that encloses some url

Tags: java, regex, amazon-web-services

i have this problem:
i have to make a regular expression which take this urls:
http://www.amazon.it/TP-LINK-TL-WR841N-Wireless-300Mbps-Ethernet/dp/B001FWYGJS?ie=UTF8&redirect=true&ref_=s9_simh_gw_p147_d0_i2

http://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B014KMQWU0/

http://www.amazon.it/gp/product/glance/B014KMQWU0/

I need a regular expression which matches the full url until the ASIN of the product (ASIN is a word of 10 capital letters)

I have write this regex but not make what i want:

```
String regex="http:\\/\\/(?:www\\.|)amazon\\.com\\/(?:gp\\ product|| gp\\ product\\ glance || [^\\/]+\\/dp|dp)\\/([^\\/]{10})";
        Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher urlAmazonMatcher = pattern.matcher(url);

        while (urlAmazonMatcher.find()) {

            System.out.println("PROVA "+urlAmazonMatcher.group(0));

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution. Finally it works :D

```
String regex="(http|www\\.)amazon\\.(com|it|uk|fr|de)\\/(?:gp\\/product|gp\\/product\\/glance|[^\\/]+\\/dp|dp)\\/([^\\/]{10})";
            Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher urlAmazonMatcher = pattern.matcher(url);
            String toReturn = null;
            while (urlAmazonMatcher.find()) {
               toReturn=urlAmazonMatcher.group(0);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
/[^/?]{10}(/$|\?)
```

This matches 10 characters that are neither / nor ? following a slash if those characters are followed by a final slash or a question mark.

You can get the part that precedes or follows the ASIN using one of the various Matcher functions.

Comment: can you make an example of the matcher function? i have tried your regex and in some link not take ASIN but ref_

Answer (score 0):

Here is my work from a previous project that was to extract URLs from text:

```
    private Pattern getUriPattern() {
    if(uriPattern == null) {
        // taken from http://labs.apache.org/webarch/uri/rfc/rfc3986.html

        //TODO implement the full URI syntax

        String genDelims  = "\\:\\/\\?\\#\\[\\]\\@";
        String subDelims  = "\\!\\$\\&\\'\\*\\+\\,\\;\\=";
        String reserved = genDelims + subDelims;
        String unreserved = "\\w\\-\\.\\~"; // i.e. ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
        String allowed = reserved + unreserved;

        // ^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
        uriPattern = Pattern.compile("((?:[^\\:/\\?\\#]+:)?//[" + allowed + "&&[^\\?\\#]]*(?:\\?([" + allowed + "&&[^\\#]]*))?(?:\\#[" + allowed + "]*)?).*");
    }
    return uriPattern;
}
```

You can use the above method as follows:

```
    Matcher uriMatcher =
    getUriPattern().matcher(text);
if(uriMatcher.matches()) {
    String candidateUriString = uriMatcher.group(1);
    try {
        new URI(candidateUriString); // check once again if you matched a URL
        // your code here
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // error handling
    }

}
```

This will catch the whole URL, including params. You can then split it up to the first occurence of '?' (if any) and take the first part. Of course, you can rework the regex too.